# Dynamically generate directory structure from text file

Tags: bash

Given the following text file which contains a list of directories, how would you automatically generate the file path if it doesn't exist.

```
apache/bin/
apache/build/
apache/error/include
apache/htdocs/images/
apache/icon/small
python/bin
python/include/python2.7
lib/pkconfig
lib/python2.7/bsddb/test
lib/python2.7/compiler
lib/python2.7/ctypes/macholib
lib/python2.7/ctypes/test
```

For example, from the root/start directory, if the line reads `apache/bin/`, I want to check if the folder `apache` exists, if it doesn't, then I create it.

After that I want to cd into it, check if the file `bin` exists, if it doesn't then I create it. Then before moving into the new line, I want to move back into the root directory (i.e. move up two levels).

How would I accomplish this in Bash?

Comment: Why would you ever change directory?  If the line ends in `/`, use `mkdir -p $line`. If it doesn't, assume the last entry is not a directory and use `mkdir -p ${line%/*}`.  Fortunately, `${line%/*}` is also correct when the line ends in `/`, so your whole script becomes `while read f; do mkdir -p ${f%/*}; done < input`

Comment: Note that this fails for files lines with any whitespace, but it's a fool's quest to make it robust (how will you handle lines that contain embedded newlines), but `mkdir -p "${f/*}"` is not an unreasonable enhancement.